# Dealing with very large expand.grid?

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I am given 31 binary variables, for simplicity let's call them
`x_1, ..., x_31`.

Each `X_i = c(0, 1)`.

I need to build a tree of options. I have used expand.grid for this but my server throws an error:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 16.0 Gb.

I am aware that I can `sparsify` this but how can I deal with the large size?

Using `sparsify` gives the same error message but with `8 Gb`.

Please advise.

Comment: At line `n` of `expand.grid(x1, ..., x31)` there is the binary expansion of `n-1`. For example, doing `as.integer(rev(intToBits(12)))[-1]` gives you line 13.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent sorry, didn't understand you. Could you please show what do you mean with an example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Too long for a comment, and @steves asked me to elaborate my comment. Take e.g.

```
> expand.grid(c(0,1), c(0,1), c(0,1))
  Var1 Var2 Var3
1    0    0    0
2    1    0    0
3    0    1    0
4    1    1    0
5    0    0    1
6    1    0    1
7    0    1    1
8    1    1    1
```

This table has `2^3=8` lines. At line `i`, this is the binary expansion of `i-1`:

```
> f <- function(i) as.integer(rev(intToBits(i)))
> f(6-1) # this gives line 6, with some heading 0's
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
```

For `expand.grid(x1, ..., x31)` there are `2^31` lines. The output of `f(i)` is a vector of 32 digits. So if you modify `f` by removing the first digit:

```
f <- function(i) as.integer(rev(intToBits(i)))[-1]
```

then `f(i-1)` exactly provides line `i` of `expand.grid(x1, ..., x31)`.

Comment: Well I'll be definitely using that in future. Good to know.